# Failing to connect to SignalR from C# SignalR Client library (404 error)

Tags: c#, signalr, .net-core-3.0

There's tons of these questions but none of them seem to work or give useful answers.  The story is the same as almost all the questions, here's what I've got:

A Hub class:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        var id = Context.ConnectionId;
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
}
```

My Startup.cs:ConfigureServices method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // other stuff that isn't relevant has been hidden
    services.AddSignalR(config =>
    {
        config.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
    });
}
```

My Startup.cs:Configure method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider)
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapHub<MyHub>("myHub");
    });
}
```

And here is my simple test program:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var url = @"http://localhost:5000";
        var hub = "MyHub";
        var hubConnection = new HubConnection(url);
        var proxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy(hub);
        await hubConnection.Start();

        hubConnection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

What have I tried?

- Searched this website for a long time checking dozens of similar posts with no luck.
- modified the URL many, many times.  I have a healthcheck endpoint on my server, which I can hit, so I know my URL is correct (at least the http://localhost:5000 part).  I've tried adding /myhub, /signalr/myhub.  I've tried using the HTTPS endpoints on port 5001 with all of the above.  I've tried changing capitalization (myhub, MyHub, myHub, MYHUB)

For the life of me I cannot get this to work.  I ***always*** get a 404.  There's really not much useful information in the console logs

> Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/signalr/myhub/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=2.1&connectionData=[%7B%22Name%22:%22MyHub%22%7D]
>   { "name": "PROJECT_NAME", "traceId": "0HLRIM50HAMJA:00000001", "url": "https://localhost/signalr/myHub/signalr/negotiate", "time": "2019-11-26T20:49:50.0222176Z", "level": "INFO", "message": "Request finished in 3.6298000000000004ms 404 ", "ElapsedMilliseconds": 3.6298000000000004, "StatusCode": 404, "ContentType": null, "EventId_Id": 2, "EventId_Name": null, "EventId": "2" }

This log message never changes.

If I hit the service with http://localhost:5000/myHub, I get a 400 error, so I can derive from that that my hub is indeed registered.  It's just something screwy with the conection.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, as a I side note, I see lots of examples using `HubConnectionBuilder` but the `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client` package doesn't seem to include it.  There is a similarly named package with `.Core` on the end, but the HubConnectionBuilder in there doesn't provide the necessary methods (I need specifically the `WithUrl` method, and it doesn't have it.)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer after some more headbanging (Stack Overflow serves as a really good rubber ducky in case you didn't know!).

The main issue here was that I fell into the pitfall of "which package do I use?".  I was using the wrong package.  I think I had "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client" and I needed to use "Microsoft.AspNet**Core**.SignalR.Client".  The ambiguity can be frustrating, to say the least.

Comment: I though the package manager complains when you try to add a .NET Framework package to a .NET Core project

Comment: It didn't as far as I could tell, although I would have appreciated it if it did